# Problem with PS3 games sharing

Tags: ps3, psn

My brother got a PS3 and I want to share my PSN games with him. When I connect on my account and I go on my list of download, when I try to download a game, I got a message telling me that there's already 2 PS3 activated with this account. I need to desactivate one of them to continue.

Everywhere on the internet, I always find that the number of PS3 activated that I can have with the same account is 5.

So, what can I do for share my game without desactivate any other PS3? If it isn't possible, how can I desactivated a PS3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They changed the rules in November to [restrict sharing](http://www.vg247.com/2011/11/18/psa-sharing-restrictions-between-psn-games-go-in-effect-today/) from 5 devices down to 2.  If you purchased content after November 18th, then these new rules are in effect.

To deactivate a console, [visit this page](http://us.playstation.com/support/answer/index.htm?a_id=796), which contains detailed instructions for both PS3 and PSP.

If you've got the PS3 you wish to deactivate, the instructions are:

- From the XMB, choose Playstation Network and then Sign In.
- Choose the Account Management option
- Choose System Activation
- Choose PS3 system
- Choose "Game"
- Choose Deactivate System

This system is now deactivated.

If you don't physically have the console you wish to deactivate, you can do so via the web.  Detailed instructions for this process are on [this page](http://us.playstation.com/support/answer/index.htm?a_id=2616).

Essentially you will need to log in to [the PSN website](https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/login.action), then go to Account, then choose Media and Devices, and from there you can deactivate all of your devices.  Note that you can only do this once every **six months** and it appears from their help pictures that it will deactivate all the devices on your account.